# jquery clone copying form elements twice on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery clone.

When i click on add button a single clone is created with above fields...upto this clone works fine

But when i click Add button twice it create three copy of clone...it create three copies and like that..

i want when i create add button it just create only one clone every time and when i click remove it remove last clone...

below is my code..

```
<fieldset id="exercises">
          <div class="exercise">  

          </div>
</fieldset>

<script>
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
  $("<div class='exercise address_box'><div class='box'></div></div>").appendTo('#exercises');
  $("#toaddress").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#sender_name").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#OrderMobileCountryCode").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#sender_no").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#presentation").clone().val("").appendTo(".box");
  $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='add_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo('.box');
  $("<br>").appendTo('.box');
  $("<br>").appendTo('#exercises');          
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.orange_btn', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: provide your full code, where is add_exercise button which will be clicked first time?

Comment: Try changing the ids to classes because once you clone them, there will be 2 elements with the same id, producing unexpected behavior. (Each id can be assigned to only one element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using box class to append cloned item to your div. First time its work fine because there is only one div with box class, But in next click there are two div and so on.

Change your add button click listener like this

```
   $('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
      var newDiv = $("<div class='exercise address_box'><div class='box'></div></div>").appendTo('#exercises');
      var boxDiv = newDiv.find(".box");
      $("#toaddress").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
      $("#sender_name").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
      $("#OrderMobileCountryCode").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
      $("#sender_no").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
      $("#presentation").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv);
      $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='add_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo(boxDiv);
      $("<br>").appendTo(boxDiv);
      $("<br>").appendTo('#exercises');   

});
```

**EDIT**

I added a code snippet here it work fine. I use red boder for box class and black border for addres_box class.

```js
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
   var newDiv = $("<div class='exercise address_box'><div class='box'></div></div>").appendTo('#exercises');
   var boxDiv = newDiv.find(".box");
   $("#toaddress").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
   $("#sender_name").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
   $("#OrderMobileCountryCode").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
   $("#sender_no").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv); 
   $("#presentation").clone().val("").appendTo(boxDiv);
   $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='add_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo(boxDiv);
   $("<br>").appendTo(boxDiv);
   $("<br>").appendTo('#exercises');   
   
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.orange_btn', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
```

```css
.address_box{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.box{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="itemsto-clone">
<input id="toaddress" value="" name="sender_name">
<input id="sender_name" value="" name="sender_name">
<input id="OrderMobileCountryCode" value="" name="sender_name">
<input id="sender_no" value="" name="sender_name">
<input id="presentation" value="" name="presentation">
  
<div>


<fieldset id="exercises">
  <div class="exercise">

  </div>
</fieldset>

<button id="add_exercise">Add Exercise</button>
```

Comment: this is working fine but i want to close this </div></div> at the end of clone bcoz i am applying border on this box and address class...

Comment: Ok so you want to append cloned items inside <div class="box"></div>.
Right now they are in outer div (address_box) right ?

Comment: no it is coming same as before...i need my clone to wrap like  <div class="exercise address_box"><div class="box"> Clone contents...</div></div>

Comment: @parcelpik I added a working snippet If it not solve your problem add full code. One more thing i just want to add you should use class instead of id in your input because its not recommended to use multiple elements with same id in a page.

Answer (score 1):

Change `id` of dynamically added button from `add_exercise` to `remove_exercise`

```
 $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='remove_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo('.box');
```

And change the remove button event as ,

```
$('#exercises').on('click', '#remove_exercise', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
```

Because your code producing element with same `id` which in turn triggering events more than once.

Try this modified code,

```
<script>
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
  $("<div class='exercise address_box'><div class='box'></div></div>").appendTo('#exercises');
  $("#toaddress").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#sender_name").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#OrderMobileCountryCode").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#sender_no").clone().val("").appendTo(".box"); 
  $("#presentation").clone().val("").appendTo(".box");
  $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='remove_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo('.box');
  $("<br>").appendTo('.box');
  $("<br>").appendTo('#exercises');          
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '#remove_exercise', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I need to wrap my clone like <div class="exercise address_box"><div class="box"> Clone contents...</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You create duplicate class name 'box' and you keep appendTo('.box')

So they just append it to all '.box' class

change your script to this

```
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
  $("<div class='exercise address_box'><div class='box'></div></div>").appendTo('.test');
  var lastbox = $(".box").last();
  $("#toaddress").clone().val("").appendTo(lastbox); 
  $("#sender_name").clone().val("").appendTo(lastbox); 
  $("#OrderMobileCountryCode").clone().val("").appendTo(lastbox); 
  $("#sender_no").clone().val("").appendTo(lastbox); 
  $("#presentation").clone().val("").appendTo(lastbox);
  $("<br><button type='button' class='orange_btn' id='add_exercise'>Remove</button>").appendTo(lastbox);
  $("<br>").appendTo(lastbox);
  $("<br>").appendTo('#exercises');          
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.orange_btn', function() {
  $(this).closest(".exercise").remove();
});
```

Comment: I need to wrap my clone like <div class="exercise address_box"><div class="box"> Clone contents...</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Since question is not very clear, here is the way to implement your requirement of cloning elements.

```js
var counter = (function(){
  var counter = 1;
  return function(){
    return  counter++;
    }
})();

$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() {  
   var clone = $('#exercises div.exercise:eq(0)').clone();
   clone.find('[id]').each(function(i,c){
     $(c).attr('id', $(c).attr('id') + counter());
     $(c).attr('placeholder', $(c).attr('id'));
   });
   $('#exercises').append(clone)
});

$('#remove_exercise').on('click', function() {
  if($('#exercises div.exercise').length !=1)
    $('#exercises div.exercise:last').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <button id="add_exercise">Add</button>
 <button id="remove_exercise">Remove</button>
</div>
<div id="exercises">
  <div class="exercise">  
    <input id="myId" placeholder="my id" />
    <input placeholder="input with no id" />
  </div>
</div>
```